# how to use angular bootstrap themes in java web application?

Tags: java, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, server

The following website contains a dashboard UI that I want to use in my website.

http://startangular.com/product/sb-admin-angular-theme/

Not just this but there are lot more available in here http://startangular.com/.
I don't understand how do I use the templates to fill in my data that I get from my backend server. All the dashboard templates I find in the link above have this grunt.js file or run independently on a nodejs server.

I don't want to use nodejs server. I just want the UI wire frames from these and use them to create my website. Is that even possible?. I am not a front end developer. I am unable to create the UI using the css links provided in the page.

Thanks.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_bootstrap.asp